# Watson speech-to-text API; support for a media URL?

Tags: ibm-cloud, speech-to-text, ibm-watson

Currently it appears that Watson's [speech-to-text API](http://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/speech-to-text/api/v1/?curl#recognize_audio_sessionless12) expects the API call to upload the audio to be recognized to the Watson servers. In a situation where the audio is already present in the cloud (say, on S3), this requires a user to download the file, then re-upload it to Watson.

Is there any way to make an API call that includes a URL to a media file?

Comment: that would be great, indeed

Comment: This is not supported, however you may want to request the feature on the IBM support site at https://developer.ibm.com/answers/

Comment: Actually, do not request that feature on dW Answers. Instead, please submit the request on the IBM Bluemix Ideas site, which is available here:
https://ibm-bluemix.uservoice.com/forums/311383-ibm-bluemix-ideas

Answer (score 0):

The API expects audio and there is no support for a URL file at the moment.
It's up to the developer to download the audio(in your case from S3) and upload it to the API.

---

The example below gets the an ogg file from Dropbox and sends it to Speech to Text for recognition.

```
var watson = require('watson-developer-cloud');
var request = require('request');
var fs = require('fs');

var speechToText = watson.speech_to_text({
  username: 'SERVICE USERNAME',
  password: 'SERVICE PASSWORD',
  version: 'v1',
  url: 'https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api'
});

var audioFile = 'https://www.dropbox.com/s/l97pe3x996fnbtg/speech.ogg?dl=1';

// create the stream
var recognizeStream = speechToText.createRecognizeStream();

// pipe in some audio
request(audioFile).pipe(recognizeStream);

// and pipe out the transcription
recognizeStream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('transcription.txt'));
```